# Crop an right-angled triangle image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I would like to extract a certain region of an image, specifically a triangular part of it. My image is of size `444x256x3`. The following picture illustrates which part I want to extract:

[image]

I would like to extract the triangle formed by the red dotted line (right-triangle).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by extract right-angled triangle. Are you trying to measure the other angles or length of sides of the triangle? If you used `image` to draw the triangle, are the edges parallel to the axis or is the triangle in some other orientation? If possible, can you upload the image?

Comment: link of the image: http://i103.photobucket.com/albums/m160/akz218/123-1.jpg

Comment: then how is that triangle defined? you have the corner points? all the points that construct the sides? all the points that are in the triangle?

Comment: @akzLeung from the image it seems like the triangle is already if the size of the images. In that case the pixel coordinates are roughly `A(0, 444)`, `B(0,0)` and `C(256,0)`, where A is the top vertex and B is the right angle triangle. Is this what you are looking for or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice function [roipoly](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/roipoly.html) which you can use to create a mask from a set of vertices:

> `BW = roipoly(I, c, r)` returns the ROI specified by the polygon described by vectors `c` and `r`, which specify the column and row indices of each vertex, respectively. `c` and `r` must be the same size.

So what you had up till now was:

```
imglena = imread('lena.png');
imshow(imglena)

siz = size(imglena);
c = [1 1      siz(2)/2];
r = [1 siz(1) siz(1)  ];
line([c c(1)],[r r(1)],'color','r','LineWidth',4);
```

[image]

with `c` and `r` the columns and rows of the vertices of the triangle.

The previously mentioned mask can now be used to extract the region of interest of the original image:

```
mask = roipoly(imglena,c,r);
imglena_cropped=bsxfun(@times, imglena, cast(mask,class(imglena)));
```

or the method I'd prefer, using plain logical indexing instead of huge matrix multiplication:

```
mask = repmat(roipoly(imglena,c,r),[1 1 3]);
imglena_cropped = 255/2*ones(size(imglena),class(imglena));
imglena_cropped(mask) = imglena(mask);
```

This way you can also more easily control the resulting background color; for example I set it to grey.

Finally you can trim the resulting image with:

```
imglena_cropped = imglena_cropped(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c),:);
```

[image]